# convert jquery into vanilla js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling with converting jquery into vanilla js.
Currently I have *form.find('input:visible')* and I am converting it to:
form.querySelectorAll('input:not([hidden])')
When I console.log both of them they are not identical. The first one is jquery, the other one is vanilla js.  [image]

**Am I missing anything? It seems that there are additional 2 nodes with vanilla js.**

Answer (score 1):

According to https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/ the `:visible` and `:hidden` selectors are not part of any CSS or Javascript specification, so they cannot be used by the built-in querySelector functions. There are several possible replacements, none of which are quite equivalent to JQuery's definition. Which one is best for you depends on your particular use case.